# How to trigger the onsubmit handler without actually submitting the form with jquery?

Tags: jquery, form-submit

I want the form's onsubmit handler to be called,but don't want to submit the form.

Is this possible with jQuery?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is. I would recommend stopping the default action of the event from being triggered, like this:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

You can also use `return false` at the end of the event handler. These two methods, however, are [not exactly equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false/1357151#1357151), so it is important to understand their differences.

Comment: @yoyo - yes, correct. Please read the link, as well as the events guide: http://docs.jquery.com/Events_(Guide)

Comment: But I don't want it that way,I need it to be submitted when certain condition is met...

Comment: So first of all mention that in the Q :) Second of all, you can 'return true' or `$(this).submit()` when a certain condition is met, which will trigger the submit.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
$('#yourForm').trigger('submit');
```

Read this [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) and [triggerHandler](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/)